# Does the imagination qualify as any form of evidence?

Tags: reality, skepticism

Suppose I believe in entities, aliens, God or higher intelligent being that are in communication with me. The catch is, there is no physical evidence for their existence. However, if such things existed in my mind, and what I thought influenced my behaviour, would they be considered existing "in theory"? The problem with the mind (from my undergraduate degree in Neuroscience) is that it is typically phenomenological. i.e. physical representation of ideas that are impossible to represent physically. For example activity in a neuron associated with the image of Britney Spears. So is this equivalent to simple "method acting" in cognitively normal people and psychosis in cognitively abnormal people? Does the imagination equate to any level of evidence? Why would I have to qualify that the imagination wasn't real? Many thanks.

Note: This is a repost from skeptics.se. Apparently this falls outside of the realm of scientific skepticism.

Comment: Einstein supposedly said, "*Imagination is more important than knowledge.*" I guess the idea is that imagination is 'generative', it comes up with new things. Not all of the new things can be true, if they differ in some ways.

Comment: That blows my mind on immediate consideration that ideas can be generated that aren't true. Then again I'm not the smartest abstract reasoner. The idea that if multiple new concepts about a physical experience differ only one can be the truth is blowing my mind.

Comment: You're welcome. "*I try to think of six impossible things before breakfast.*" (Alice in Wonderland) Now, *after* breakfast, it's a different story.

Comment: We can imagine and believe in lies, falsehoods and non-existent things. This is a fact. QED

Comment: You may be interested in [The unsoundness of arguments from conceivability](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228718895_The_Unsoundness_of_Arguments_From_Conceivability)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case you propose, the fact that you believe in those beings is not evidence that they exist - even in theory. However, if you have some good reason for thinking that they might exist, it could be accepted as a theoretical hypothesis, pending empirical evidence.

In philosophy, it is often assumed that if something can be imagined, that proves that it is (logically) possible. Descartes' evil demon in his Meditations is a case in point. See [Descartes Evil Genius (Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/#EvilGeniDoub) Whether it would be a theoretical possibility depends on the theory you have in mind.

Comment: I suppose if I could train a rat to believe cheese is bad based on operant conditioning, I don't see why a higher intelligence couldn't train me to believe in my own demons. I don't know, it's fairly redundant isn't it if it is not reproducible? I'll check that link out immediately. Thank you.

Comment: Imagination, as far as I can tell, serves to *weaken* arguments by fielding *possibilities* which are *alternatives* to the conclusion of an argument. In short, they're *anti-evidence*. Here's an excerpt from an *imagined* conversation: Yes, yes, but it *could* be that <insert imagination>

Comment: Well yes I suppose that could be the case, but in reality all I am assuming is that can I be a true skeptic if I allow imagination some degree of validity in the interpretation of my personal experience?

Comment: @Agent Smith Well, it is true that one application of imagination is to weaken arguments. But that wouldn't work against an argument that is valid and sound, would it? And there are other applications. Other applications might be is to develop hypotheses or to entertain the kids, or inspire the troops.

Comment: @OpenSauce I'm not sure what you have in mind. But so long as you don't mistake imagination for truth, it should be all right.

Comment: @LudwigV, agreed.

Comment: @OpenSauce You may be interested in [The unsoundness of arguments from conceivability](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228718895_The_Unsoundness_of_Arguments_From_Conceivability)

Answer (score 3):

One problem if you accept imagination as evidence, is that you can imagine pretty much anything. It is too arbitrary and open-ended, there is no necessity. "Evidence" seems to lose its meaning and value as a filter for what is the case and what is not.

Using imagination to generate hypotheses can be productive if the imagination is grounded somehow. But saying "I can imagine it, therefore this is some level of evidence that it exists" is not productive. After all, I can imagine flying saucers, teapots orbiting the Sun, etc etc. without end and without reason. It seems it's just "noise" from an epistemic point of view.

Here is something to consider: I can imagine, for example, both that there are parallel universes and that parallel universes do not exist. Which alternative should get any level of "evidence" from my imaginative act? If one of the two possibilities seems to be supported by prior evidence, then one of the two possibilities might be more reasonable to imagine. However, it's not the imaginative act as much as the prior evidence that would lend support to the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

We should clarify the term **“evidence”**. In a court of law, evidence is anything that may be examined, but it does not necessarily prove any given conclusion. On the other hand, in common language many people treat the word evidence as *inherently* having a conclusion; i.e. "proof". In the former sense, you'd say "a piece of evidence", and in the latter sense you'd say "evidence *of* something".

I hold to the former definition, that evidence itself is not proof. Instead,   evidence needs sound *arguments* in order to prove a conclusion.

In this sense, evidence is anything that can be observed. It might be used (with arguments) to attempt to prove a conclusion, or it might not be.

Here's an example of an invalid argument: "I imagined this, therefore it is real". That would be a *Non Sequitur*.

On the other hand, if you argued "these thirty subjects imagined the same thing at the same time, therefore my mind control apparatus is working" — that seems more notable, however the reasoning is still implied. The reasoning of this argument would be something like: "statistically this is unlikely to occur without an outside force, and the only explainable source for that was the mind control apparatus".

You may notice that the above paragraph does not mention the word "proof". Basically nothing can be completely proven. When people speak of proof, they imply "beyond a reasonable doubt", which means there is no reasonable reason to doubt what is being argued. That doesn't mean it's true, however. Absolute truth only exists in the mind of philosophers and God.

When evidence and arguments are combined, they yield a conclusion. However, if the evidence is false or the arguments are invalid, the conclusion is unproven. Evidence can be false if the person is lying or mistaken, and the arguments can be invalid based on the rules of logic. However, how do you *know* whether the evidence is false? In reality as humans we come up with a probability or likelihood through a process called *reasoning*.

So imaginings are evidence, but it's only when combined with arguments that evidence can prove a conclusion, and an error in any part can invalidate that conclusion. Distinguishing these terms (evidence, arguments, and conclusions) is critical to clearly understanding "proof".